# How to free zval in PHP5 created with MAKE_STD_ZVAL?

Tags: php, c

How to release the variable created with the following code?

```
zval *zval_ = nullptr;
MAKE_STD_ZVAL(zval_);
ZVAL_NULL(zval_);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has garbage-collected memory managment.  You don't generally release it manually/forceably, it gets GC'd when there are no more references to it.  You must, however, use references properly.

In the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php), have a look at the `Z_ADDREF`, `Z_DECREF`, and `zval_ptr_dtor`.  There is a `Z_FREE` as well, but you should not generally use this - you don't want to forceably free a `zval` that is referenced in other "live" (reachable) values!

For an overview of how to use the reference system with concrete examples of the corresponding plain PHP code, see the [reference tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) in the docs.

To answer your question exactly:   `MAKE_STD_ZVAL` starts the value off with a reference count of 1.  So, a single call

```
 zval_ptr_dtor(zval_);
```

will remove that reference and clear the variable at next GC iteration (and unlike `Z_FREE` this will do the right thing even if you pass the value to a function which might store it somewhere and increment its ref count, etc...)